# which folder do I do a git init

Tags: android, git

My project folder is called `c:\project\SampleApp`, within `SampleApp` are all the files for my Android/Java project. I would like to start using git.

Do I change my directory and do a `git init` like this:

```
cd c:\project\SampleApp
git init
```

or do i do the following:

```
c:\project
git init
```

I tried to look through some documentation but it was not clear. I also tried to watch videos on this but that didn't help.

Therefore I just dont know if I must init the entire SampleApp, or if I must first enter it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're initialising a new repository, you have to enter the directory:

```
cd DirectoryName
git init
```

However, if you're cloning an existing project, the project folder will be generated automatically. Cloning an existing project doesn't require calling `git init`.

`git clone` therefore has to be called in the parent directory and will generate a new folder, containing the existing project.

Comment: well, actually i did git clone and downloaded from an existing repository on github , so are you saying i must do a cd c:\project\SampleApp ?

Comment: @aedfsaef, no. If you cloned the repository you shouldn't run `git init` at all. You've already *got* a repository, so there is no need to create one.

Comment: There are two options: Cloning an existing repository (`git clone`), which has to be done in the parent folder, or creating a blank new project (`git init`), which has to be done in the project folder. You need to do the first one.

Comment: i cloned the project and did NOT do a git init, rather i did a cd c:\project\SampleApp and now my git status seems to work., I think that was the solution

Comment: ok one last question, I just want to push up one file, waht is the git command for that

Comment: Change the file, and then add it to the staging area using `git add -A`. Afterwards, make a commit with `git commit -m "any message"`. In order to push that commit, use `git push` (or `git push origin master` if it doesn't work)